# ./build.sh inari fails trying to build Firefox OS for inari device

Tags: linux, firefox, ubuntu, firefox-os

I am trying to build firefox os on a Ubuntu 12.04 64 (4Gb RAM,30GB of free space, GCC-4.8.1 and g++4.8.1) following strictly all the steps from developers.mozilla and the true it is not working and I need help from community in the very last step, with my inari device connected in dev mode and visible from adb devices ./build.sh inari is giving me this error:

```
Blob setup script has changed, re-running  Pulling files from
**../../../backup-inari**  cat: **../../../backup-inari/system/build.prop**: No such file or directory  Found firmware with build ID Pulling "`libOmxAacDec.so`"  cp: cannot stat    
**../../../backup-inari/system/lib/libOmxAacDec.so'**: No such file or directory Failed to pull `libOmxAacDec.so`. Giving up.

Build failed!

Build with `|./build.sh -j1|` for better messages
```

If all else fails, use `|rm -rf objdir-gecko|` to clobber gecko and `|rm -rf out|` to clobber everything else.

i tried also doing this rm stuff and start from the beginning with ./config.sh with the same result

Comment: What does it says when you type `adb root` in a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be causing because you either have a different version from what the builder is expecting. Or that you don't have root access to the device.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1121600

Please, report it and I could take it a look. Tell what branch are you trying to compile and any other relevant information.